# Strange Azure Resource Group Deployment Error

Tags: c#, azure, azure-devops

As part of my release definition, I have specific a Azure Resource Group Deployment
task with action of Create or Update.

When I start a new release, the Azure Resource Group Deployment encounters the following error

> 2018-11-27T20:52:54.1969890Z ##[error]At least one resource deployment
>   operation failed. Please list deployment operations for details.
>   Please see https://aka.ms/arm-debug for usage details.
>
> 2018-11-27T20:52:54.1978636Z ##[debug]Processed: ##vso[task.issue
>   type=error;]At least one resource deployment operation failed. Please
>   list deployment operations for details. Please see
>   https://aka.ms/arm-debug for usage details.
>
> 2018-11-27T20:52:54.1979036Z ##[error]Details:
>
> 2018-11-27T20:52:54.1979251Z ##[debug]Processed: ##vso[task.issue
>   type=error;]Details:
>
> 2018-11-27T20:52:54.1979531Z ##[error]Conflict: {
>
> "code": "Conflict",
>
> "message": "Domain name dev-xxxxcu-tm.trafficmanager.net already
>   exists. Please choose a different DNS prefix."
>
> } undefined
>
> 2018-11-27T20:52:54.1979791Z ##[debug]Processed: ##vso[task.issue
>   type=error;]Conflict: {%0D%0A  "code": "Conflict",%0D%0A  "message":
>   "Domain name dev-xxxxcu-tm.trafficmanager.net already exists. Please
>   choose a different DNS prefix."%0D%0A} undefined
>
> 2018-11-27T20:52:54.1979957Z ##[debug]task result: Failed
>
> 2018-11-27T20:52:54.1980125Z ##[error]Task failed while creating or
>   updating the template deployment.
>
> 2018-11-27T20:52:54.1980303Z ##[debug]Processed: ##vso[task.issue
>   type=error;]Task failed while creating or updating the template
>   deployment.
>
> 2018-11-27T20:52:54.1981450Z ##[debug]Processed: ##vso[task.complete
>   result=Failed;]Task failed while creating or updating the template
>   deployment.
>
> 2018-11-27T20:52:54.1991258Z ##[section]Finishing: Azure
>   Deployment:Create Or Update Resource Group action on
>   $(Release.EnvironmentName)-xxxxcu-rg

I've reviewed the azure template json and don't see anything relative to this error. There are variables related to the Traffic Manager, see below:

```
"names-traffic-manager": {
  "type": "string",
  "metadata": {
    "description": "The name of the traffic manager instance"
  }
},

{
  "apiVersion": "2015-11-01",
  "type": "Microsoft.Network/trafficManagerProfiles",
  "name": "TrafficManager",
  "location": "global",
  "properties": {
    "profileStatus": "Enabled",
    "trafficRoutingMethod": "Priority",
    "dnsConfig": {
      "relativeName": "[parameters('names-traffic-manager')]",
      "ttl": 30
    },
    "monitorConfig": {
      "protocol": "HTTPS",
      "port": 443,
      "path": "/"
    }
  }
},
```

Thanks for input...I've also verified the Traffic Manager profile is correct in Azure Portal

Comment: Have you carefully read the error message and attempted to correct the stated cause of the problem, which is **Domain name dev-xxxxcu-tm.trafficmanager.net already exists. Please choose a different DNS prefix**?

Comment: I think what is being suggested here is to try a completely different resource domain name for traffic manager as a resource has already taken the name you are using.

Comment: I understand what the Conflict message means, but am unsure where to correct the issue.  There are properties related to traffic manager in the azuredeploy.json file, I've updated the OP with that.

Answer (score 1):

You need to change the traffic manager `relativeName`, you would do that at this line:

```
"relativeName": "TrafficManager-unique-name-3245235",
```

You can also use a parameter to construct the name on the fly:

```
"relativeName": "[concat(parameters('names-traffic-manager'), '-traffic-manager')]
```

Comment: Thanks! However, I'm unsure as to why I need to change the Traffic manager name? What exactly is the template deploy doing to generate that Conflict error? 


When I inspect the task closer in Azure Pipelines, I see there is a variable for TM named Names.TrafficManager with a value of $(Release.EnvironmentName)-xxxxcu-tm

This variable is used in the Override Template section of the Task:

-names-traffic-manager $(Names.TrafficManager) 

This appears to be constructing the name on the fly and then updating that relative value in the template?

Comment: well, traffic managed name has to be unique across all of the azure resources (not just for you, for every azure client). i dont know what your step does (and if it works), but the name that gets used by the template is taken by somebody else. so you need to fix that.

Comment: also, looking at your template. tm name is hardcoded in it. dns name changes. which i dont know if it helps. yeah, it appears TM name doesnt matter, dns config part does

Comment: thanks for the fast response. after more research I have discovered an external vendor has implemented a Web Application Firewall in Azure. Before this, I could resolve the traffic manager url. now I cannot. this could be related?

Comment: on a whim I changed the value of Names.TrafficManager from referencing the traffic manager Azure name (dev-xxxxcu-tm) to the actual website url. now the release runs fine without error and deploys both primary and secondary. 

thoughts?

Comment: well, that is expected, as you are providing a name that is not yet occupied by somebody else (or even you). so that part is nothing special. TM dns name HAS TO BE UNIQUE across all azure

Answer (score 0):

Due to the implementation of a WAF (Web Application Firewall) by an outside vendor, the trafficmanager instance was no longer accessible by http or https requests, only from sources that were allowed through the WAF.

To work around this issue I simply set the value for the TM variable to be the related azure instance (dev.xxxx.org, test.xxxx.org and www.xxxx.org). This fixed the issue and the release is running without error now.

Thanks to everyone for the help. This was my first experience with Azure Pipelines so its been a big learning curve, basically got thrown in and told to swim :D